# albedo, height, roughness? Texture download included a bunch of files. How do I properly use them?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I have downloaded a seamless concrete texture, but I'm not sure what to do with each file.

From what I understand, each texture is used to apply a certain effect on the object, but no tuturial has given a clear pathway on what each one means and how it needs to be used. The folder included these 5 files: albedo, ao (ambient occlusion?), height, normal, roughness. How do I properly utilize this?

It seems like there's no right answer at this point, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle with this as well, but I found that activating Node Wrangler in the add-on gave me access to a great shortcut for creating principled shaders.  If you go to the node editor and change the diffuse node created when you make a new cycles material to principled then while it is selected  hit ctrl, shift, T it opens a screen to let you select your images.  Highlight all and then click the open button and it will build a proper principled shader tree putting them into the right spots.  I haven't tried it with an AO file though because I'm not sure what that's for and I was under the impression Blender didn't use them, but I could be wrong about that.  Hope this helps you out a little bit.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! AO maps are an optional way to add ambient occlusion to the material. To use them, use them as a mix factor between the diffuse texture and black. Then, you can ramp it and adjust the mix factor slider to control the darkness in the cracks/crevices

Comment: Wow, what a useful addon! Thank you all for the help!